# What are some of SOA / BPEL best practices?

Tags: soa, bpel

Looking for some resources on SOA / BPEL best practices. Specially BPEL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A quick Google search reveals that Oracle provides [SOA Best Practices - The BPEL Cookbook](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/bpel_cookbook/index.html) which is an online article collection of some best practices
2. A random book search revealed [BPEL Cookbook](http://bpelworld.com/?p=76) - subtitled *Best Practices for SOA-based integration and composite applications development: Ten practical real-world case studies combining business … management and web services orchestration*, the interesting about this is its publishing date, just 12 days ago.